# bind 2 buttons with equal functionality on different activities

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have a 2 diffetent activity with button. These buttons have a equal functionality and equal ids. What is the best way to create listener of these buttons? The very long "switch" or setting "OnClick" state? On the second way I may forget to change something.

The first way:

XML:

```
<Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_main_continue"
                android:text="@string/btn_main_continue" />
```

JAVA:

```
View button = findViewById(R.id.btn_main_about);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
                ...
            }
        }
    });
```

The second way:

XML:

```
<Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_main_continue"
                android:text="@string/btn_main_continue"
                android:onClick="onClickButtonAbout" />
```

JAVA:

```
public void onClickButtonAbout(View view) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What is the best way?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest making your activity implement an OnClickListener, then override the onClick method in there with your switch case statements inside.
This way, you just need to put eg. button.setOnClickListener(this) in your activity.
It is kind of clean and avoids overstepping.
On another note, try to keep the ids of the XML layouts unique.